# azure function - writing lActive Directory users to a file in async manner

Tags: azure-functions, microsoft-graph-api

I am getting all users from Azure AD using Graph API, within an Azure Function.
The resulting list of users is quite large and returning it via the HTTP response body is not ideal.

I have been having difficulty altering my azure function to run in an efficient async manner.

The IGraphServiceUsersCollectionPage is async, so it wont block program flow.
This leads me to believe i can write each page of 100 users to a file as they are extracted, without blocking reading of the next page.

I would appreciate advise on how the code might be structured to allow this.

Function code is shown below. Right now, it runs sequentially, returning a large list.

```
[FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            string tenantId = "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx";
            string clientId = "xxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxxx";
            string clientSecretValue = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

            List<User> users = new List<User>();
            var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };


            var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
            tenantId, clientId, clientSecretValue);

            var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

            IGraphServiceUsersCollectionPage usersPage = await graphClient
            .Users
            .Request()
            .Select("Department,DisplayName,Mail,Id")
            .GetAsync();


            users.AddRange(usersPage.CurrentPage);


            while (usersPage.NextPageRequest != null)
            {
                usersPage = await usersPage.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();
                users.AddRange(usersPage.CurrentPage);
            }

            return new OkObjectResult(users);
        }

        private static void writeToStorage()
        {
            //write To Storage
        }
```

**I am aware hardcoding secrets is a terrible idea, this is just a POC right now.

Answer (score 0):

This can be also done by using the .top() in your code. Below code is for users similarly you can use for groups.

```
IUserCollectionPage users = graphClient.users()
        .buildRequest(requestOptions)
        .select("userPrincipalName,mail")
        .top(999)
        .get();
```

This can also be used for both [User](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp%2Cpowershell#example-1-get-all-users) and [Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#example-1-get-a-list-of-groups).Hope this is helpfull.